# Polynomial Vector Space Particular question

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the basis for the polynomial vector space such that f(0)=f(2)?

My thought process: let g be a polynomial such that g= a+bx+cx^2+...zx^n

g(0)=g(2) (=)

a = a + 2b + 4c + ... 2^nz (=)
b + 2c + ... + 2^-1z = 0

Now how do I determine the basis? I assume it will be something similar to:

(1, x^2-2x, x^3-4x, ... x^n - 2^(n-1)x),

but I can't prove it. I can gather that by inspection, because this would guarantee that everything would cut itself out except for the independent term.

Please help?

Comment: Hmm, your guess seems to work.  The elements in your proposed basis are linearly independent, and to show that they span the space one can induct on the degree of the polynomials.  What do you mean by "everything would cut itself out except for the independent term"?

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we're working on $\;V:=\Bbb R_n[x]=$ all the real polynomials of degree up to $\;n\;$ , so $\;\dim_{\Bbb R}V=n+1\;$ :

$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\;:\;f(0)=f(2)\iff a_0=a_0+2a_1+4a_2+\ldots+2^na_n\implies$$

$$a_1+2a_2+\ldots+2^{n-1}a_n=0$$

This last equation determines a hyperplane $\;H\;$ (a *proper* vector subspace of maximal (i.e., $\;n\;$ ) dimension) in $\;V\;$ , and as such it is the kernel of a non-zero linear functional, and in fact

$$H=\ker\phi\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;\phi:V\to \Bbb R\;\;\text{defined by}\;\;\phi(p(x)):=p(2)-p(0)$$

A possible basis of $\;H\;$ is

$$\{1,\;2x-x^2\;,\;4x-x^3\,,\,8x-x^4\,,\,\ldots,2^{n-1}x-x^n\;\}$$

which, of course, it is just *your* basis, but now you can prove it actually is a basis since the elements in that set are clearly linearly independent (check the degree of each element), and we have the correct ammount of them: $\;n\;$ .